# JDNConvertibleCalendarDateAdapter library is not compatible in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

I'm developing an angular project and my current angular version is 9. I have got some peer dependency warnings related to 'JDNConvertibleCalendarDateAdapter' library when I try to update @angular/material to angular 10. Is there any way to fix this problem? I need to use hijri calender in my project. I'm a beginner in this field and please help me to fix this.

This is the error I got while updating:

Package "jdnconvertiblecalendardateadapter" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/material" (requires "^9.2.1", would install "10.2.0").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/dhlab-basel/JDNConvertibleCalendarDateAdapter/pull/25 updates the lib to Angular 10. Once this is done, we will publish a new version on npm.